# jQuery TypeError: $(…).attr(…) is undefined?

Tags: jquery

The following error TypeError: $(…).attr(…) is undefined is occuring on this line of code:

```
$('iframe').each(function(index,item) { 
    if($(item).attr('src').match(/(https?:)?\/\/www\.youtube\.com/)) {
```

Why can't I call the `.attr()` method in this situation?

The whole function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(typeof YOUTUBE_VIDEO_MARGIN == 'undefined') {
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_MARGIN=5;
  }
  $('iframe').each(function(index,item) {
    if($(item).attr('src').match(/(https?:)?\/\/www\.youtube\.com/)) {
      var w=$(item).attr('width');
      var h=$(item).attr('height');
      var ar = h/w*100;
      ar=ar.toFixed(2);
      //Style iframe    
      $(item).css('position','absolute');
      $(item).css('top','0');
      $(item).css('left','0');    
      $(item).css('width','100%');
      $(item).css('height','100%');
      $(item).css('max-width',w+'px');
      $(item).css('max-height', h+'px');        
      $(item).wrap('<div style="max-width:'+w+'px;margin:0 auto; padding:'+YOUTUBE_VIDEO_MARGIN+'px;" />');
      $(item).wrap('<div style="position: relative;padding-bottom: '+ar+'%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" />');
    }
  });
});
```

And the HTML which contains the `src` attribute

```
<iframe class="videoborder" width="680" height="382" frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/2qOYDpF24cs?rel=0&controls=0&
showinfo=0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%;
height: 100%; max-width: 680px; max-height: 382px;">
```

Comment: It's calling `.match` with an undefined LHS that's producing the error, not `.attr()` per-se.

Comment: A side issue: Dont Repeat Yourself. All of those jQuery calls can be chained onto one `$(item)` (or `$(this)` if you folloow the answer given). Some can also be combined into one method - eg `.css()` can change multiple css properties in one go.

Comment: @Alnitak What is the LHS expression in this case?

Comment: @IanButler apparently, it's `undefined`.  Either the `src` attribute doesn't exist, or is not accessible (for security reasons?).  I've never tried using iframes myself so I'm not sure which.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/phLofj46/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prop()` instead of `attr()`. There can be other `iframes` in your page has no `src` attribute. So using `attr()` you get `undefined` for `$(item).prop('src')` if item have no attribute `src`. Hence the error.

```
$(item).prop('src');
```

**Your code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(typeof YOUTUBE_VIDEO_MARGIN == 'undefined') {
    YOUTUBE_VIDEO_MARGIN=5;
  }
  $('iframe').each(function(index,item) {
    if($(item).prop('src').match(/(https?:)?\/\/www\.youtube\.com/)) {
      var w=$(item).attr('width');
      var h=$(item).attr('height');
      var ar = h/w*100;
      ar=ar.toFixed(2);
      //Style iframe    
      $(item).css('position','absolute');
      $(item).css('top','0');
      $(item).css('left','0');    
      $(item).css('width','100%');
      $(item).css('height','100%');
      $(item).css('max-width',w+'px');
      $(item).css('max-height', h+'px');        
      $(item).wrap('<div style="max-width:'+w+'px;margin:0 auto; padding:'+YOUTUBE_VIDEO_MARGIN+'px;" />');
      $(item).wrap('<div style="position: relative;padding-bottom: '+ar+'%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" />');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: or even just `item.src`.   FWIW, and IMHO, this is a poor explanation.  The real issue is that the _attribute_ `src` may not exist on the iframe element, thus returning a "null" value from `.attr`.  However the _property_ that backs that attribute always has a value, even if it's just an empty string.  It has nothing to do with "other" iframes on the page.

Comment: @Alnitak you are right about `item.src`, but see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1k9synh0/). So if there is a `iframe` without `src` attribute defined, then here `$(item).attr('src').match(/(https?:)?\/\/www\.youtube\.com/)` we are doing `match` with `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying - he was getting an unusable value from `.attr()`.  However I was _also_ saying that there's no point using `$(element).prop('src')` when you can just write the optimally efficient (and easier to read) `element.src` instead.